Is the chart correct by using "recycling" and not "recycle"?
The chart uses recycling and not recycle. Is the legend correct? So, landfill and compost can be used as a noun but recycle cannot?  Collins dictionary shows it can be used as a noun:
7. the act or process of recycling

Recycle/recycling accounts for less than 10% of total waste disposed
in Toronto.



Which dictionary says that recycle can be a noun?

@KateBunting https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/recycle

Recycling is correct, but as a label, "Recycle" would be okay, too.

Thanks. I see they list it under the American definitions, but don't give an example of its use. I wonder if any American contributors can comment on this? In my (British) experience we speak of sending rubbish for recycling or to be recycled.

@KateBunting As an American I can't formulate a reasonable sentence using "recycle" as a noun.

@AndyBonner - They can in Phoenix, AZ, apparently - Weekly trash & recycling collection (recycle is taken to Phoenix transfer stations as part of IGA).

Also in Ashwaubenon, WI: Garbage is typically collected once per week on a Monday - Friday schedule. Recycle is collected every-other week on your garbage day

I live in Maryland (in the mid-Atlantic) and have never in my 6.5 decades encountered recycle as a noun… at least not before this question.

I haven't any objection in principle to a noun derived from a verb; I have seen 'vomit', 'spit', and 'scrap' used that way. I'm sure there must be others.

Ditto what the other murkins said.

I found recycle used as a noun (recycle is taken...) in an article on an American college website but the author's name is Xiong.

There is a disturbing trend in English since the mid 2000s to nominalize almost any verb. It used to be that only certain verbs were used this way, but the list has grown. For example, 'This is a big ask.' The verb 'to ask' was never nominalized before then. I find it ugly and awkward, but I suppose language changes over time.

When a verb is the subject of a sentence or phrase, it takes the suffix -ing, gerunds are often said to act like nouns. For example, ”Making breakfast is one of many jobs that staff do” i.e. The making of breakfast. "Recycling plastics is costly and inefficient”

Note that landfill was originally a noun and compost is from a Latin adjective that was used as a noun (source: OED), while recycle was originally a verb. So using landfill and compost as nouns is totally logical.

The activity is recycling.

'Recycle' is only used as a noun for the process of recycling - it isn't used as a noun for the actual waste itself. So, as your graph scale refers to "waste" and not to the disposal process, it doesn't seem appropriate.
Although it might seem odd to call the waste 'recycling', that is what most people (certainly in the UK) would call it (eg "the recycling is collected every two weeks"). A countable noun for the same thing is "recyclables".

I wonder, @Astralbee, how you can make such an unconditional, blanket assertion given the several comments to the OP that report having encountered counter examples.

@PaulTanenbaum I wonder how you, Paul, believe the blanket assertions of others but not me? It's almost like it's personal?

@PaulTanenbaum Ah, I see how you are confused - it is used as a noun but not for the actual waste itself. Well that's fair enough, but it doesn't fit the OP's context, and if you knew and comprehended that fully then you would have appreciated my answer was still helpful and correct in the context. Comments are supposed to help improve answers, not just blanketly tear them down. I think some people on here should be ashamed of their elitist behaviour.

“Blanketly tearing down” this answer, was I? The comments to which I referred made existence claims about individual locations, whereas yours made a universal claim (“‘Recycle’ isn’t used as a noun”). Because I “engage respectfully” here, I am sure that you “knew and comprehended that fully” enough to appreciate the distinction. But I don’t know, perhaps it was simply the shameful elitist in me.

Paul is right: recycle
2 of 2
noun
: the process of recycling Merriam Webster
